# Series expansion for logarithm

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, logarithms

> Find the Taylor series for
> $$ 
> f(x)=\int^x_1 \ln\left(2t^2 - 4t+11\right)\,dt \text{, expanded at about } x_0=1
> $$
> and find the radius of convergence of the series.

**My approach:** First, I found the derivative of $f(x)$ using Newton-Leibniz theorem, which is
$$f'(x) = \ln(2x^2-4x+11)$$

Then,
$$
\begin{split}
\ln\left(2x^2-4x+11\right)
 &= \ln\left(11 \left(\frac{2x^2}{11} - \frac{4x}{11} +1\right) \right) \\
 &= \ln 11 + \ln\left(\underbrace{\frac{2x^2}{11}
                      - \frac{4x}{11}}_{u(x)} +1\right) \\
 &= \ln 11 + \ln(1+u(x))
\end{split}
$$

And here I'm stuck on. I know the formula for Taylor's expansion of $\ln(1+x)$, but I'm not sure even if it is applicable here and I'm not sure how to find the radius, as well.

Looking forward for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite it as
$$\ln(2x^2-4x+11) = \ln2 + \ln\left((x-1)^2 + \frac92\right) = \ln 9 + \ln\left(1 + \frac{2}{9}(x-1)^2\right)$$
Now, use the expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ since $\dfrac92(x-1)^2 \to 0$ as $x\to 1$.

Comment: can you give me a hint about the radius of convergence? I know that of $ln(1+x)$ is $(-1,1]$, but what about the result?

Comment: @SimonJachson $\left|\dfrac92(x-1)^2 \right| \le 1$

Comment: And in the expansion, I get the $"$standard$"$ one $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$, because x equals zero. Did I understand you right? Thank you!

Comment: @SimonJachson Yes, it will be of this form but with our current expression instead of $x$. Also, don't forget about $\int_1^x$.